# Python generator which yields lines based on defined separator

Tags: python, generator, yield

Trying to write a generator function which reads in a file one line at a time and yields an output with each item as a separate element within a list based on the defined separator. So for an input of:

```
ID|Name|Major
1234|Jane Heng|History
2334|Nandini Khola|Computer Science
6345|Ben Johnson|Data Science
```

The ideal output would be:

```
[1234, Jane Heng, History]
[2334, Nandini Khola, Computer Science]
[6345, Ben Johnson, Data Science]
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
def file_reader(path, fields, sep, header):
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        if not os.path.isfile(path):
            raise FileNotFoundError(
                errno.ENOENT, os.strerror(errno.ENOENT), path)
        for line in file:
            count = 0 #Initialize line counter

            while True:
                i = line.find(sep)
                count += 1
                if i == -1:
                    break
                fieldlist = [x for x in (line.rstrip(sep) for line in file) if x]
                # if header is True:
                #     if len(fieldlist) == fields:
                #         count = 1  # Start from the second line if there is header
                #         continue
                #     else:
                #         raise ValueError(
                #             f'{path} has {len(fieldlist)} fields in header but expected {fields} fields!')
                if len(fieldlist) != fields:
                    raise ValueError(f'{path} has {len(fieldlist)} fields on line {count} but expected {fields} fields!')
                yield fieldlist
```

But testing with:

```
gen = file_reader('/path/to/file.txt', 3, sep='|', header=True)
print(next(gen))
```

I get:

```
['1234|Jane Heng|History\n', '2334|Nandini Khola|Computer Science\n', '6345|Ben Johnson|Data Science']
```

And if I try something like

```
for ID, Name, Major in file_reader('/path/to/file.txt', 3, sep='|', header=True):
    print(f"id: {ID} name: {Name} major: {Major}")
```

I get an output of:

```
cwid: 1234|Jane Heng|History
 name: 2334|Nandini Khola|Computer Science
 major: 6345|Ben Johnson|Data Science

ValueError: /path/to/file.txt has 0 fields on line 2 but expected 3 fields!
```

Clearly the `\n` results in everything being read as 1 line, hence the ValueError exception.

The header code block is currently commented out, but the idea would be to only continue if the header has the expected number of fields. So if there are only 2 fields in the header, then the ValueError exception would be raised. When the block is commented in, I get:

```
ValueError: /path/to/file.txt has 0 fields in header but expected 3 fields!
```

Any advice on how I could get the desired output?

Comment: you are reinventing the wheel - look at the `csv` module. There are also other problems, e.g. if file does not exists, you will get error before you even reach the `if` statement.

Comment: @buran yeah, that whole check is pointless since `open` would raise the appropriate error anywa

Comment: Thanks for that pointer, removed that block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `split('|')` seems to get the job done:

```py
def file_reader(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        if not os.path.isfile(path):
            raise FileNotFoundError(
                errno.ENOENT, os.strerror(errno.ENOENT), path)
            
        result = []
        header_length = 0
            
        for i, line in enumerate(file):
            if i == 0:
                header_length = len(line.strip().split('|'))
            else:
                contents = line.strip().split('|')
                if len(contents) != header_length:
                    raise ValueError() #your desired error message here
                else:
                    result.append(contents)
                
        return result

result = file_reader(path)
for r in result:
    print(r)
```

Out:

```
['1234', 'Jane Heng', 'History']
['2334', 'Nandini Khola', 'Computer Science']
['6345', 'Ben Johnson', 'Data Science']
```

Comment: This works for the specified input, but if the second line is `2334|Nandini Khola|Computer Science|Hello` for example, no ValueError is raised

Comment: You can always add a check to see if each row is the same length as the header. If not, `raise ValueError`. Otherwise, append to your results. I've edited my answer to implement that approach. You could also use `try`/`except` to catch and handle the error so that all the rows that *do* conform to the header length are added to the file without shutting down your program.

Comment: You're missing a parentheses at the end, in `print(r`

Comment: OK I added a check to see if the header length equals the specified number of fields, if not, `ValueError` is raised. Otherwise it continues and another check for the number of items on each line compared to the number of specified fields is performed. 

What would be the most efficient way to check for the header? If `header=False` then include the first line in the printout, otherwise first check number of items in first line before skipping it in the printout. Copying and pasting the block for the content with `if header is True` and `if header is False` doesn't seem the most efficient...

Comment: I suppose you could change `if i == 0` to something along the lines of `if (i==0) and (header)`, where you've already defined `header` as a `bool` that is `True` if there is a header and `False` otherwise. The way you choose to set `header` will be dependent on how you identify whether you have a header. If you can do it programmatically based on the data structure it could happen inside the function. Alternatively, if you want to set the variable manually you could include it in the function definition like `def file_reader(path, header=True):`

Comment: Added `if i == 0 and header is True:` and specified it as a parameter in the function as well - got it to produce expected output! Thank you so much for your help!